# Could not build wheels for +kivy, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

При попытке поставить фреймворк с помощью команды pip install kivy==2.1.0

Получаю ошибку

**Could not build wheels for +kivy, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects**

Ставлю в виртуальную среду venv через IDE PyCharm.

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решена командой:

```
python -m pip install --upgrade pip setuptools
```

Она обновит pip и setuptools.

Если у вас нету setuptools то нужно поставить.